# Does "graphically" convey the same negative connotation as "graphic"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Graphic can mean something similar to "visual", but it can also mean something like offensive (eg: graphic content).

I want to convey the same meaning as visually or illustrated (but can't use them) and I was thinking about using "graphically"

I would like to know if people reading "graphically" immediately think of :
a/ the visual meaning
b/ the offensive meaning.

I want to use this word in an educational context by putting emphasis on the fact I will rely on pictures / graphics / diagrams.

Comment: A graphic content warning doesn't always mean that something is "offensive", it can just mean "disturbing" (such as medical footage).

Comment: _Graphic_ doesn't actually imply 'offensive' - it's just that a description of a violent or gruesome scene is sometimes described as graphic in the sense that it is very vivid and explicit, like seeing a detailed picture of the scene.

Comment: You can't replace "graphic" with "graphically" because one is an adjective and the other an adverb. Do you mean "graphical"? Do you have a specific sentence?